# HTML Image Question

Tags: html, image, https

I'm trying to do some HTML layouts, and pretty much my problem comes in here:

```
<img src = "https://something.com/image.png">
```

The image can be displayed in a browser when navigating to the URL, but not in Microsoft Visual Studio (or the browser when loading this HTML page), it displays as a broken image instead.  This leads me to believe it cannot be linked to in such a way (as I can view other images this way).  I'm wondering if it has anything to do with it requiring a secure http connection and if there's any way around this.

Basically, the picture comes up when the url is navigated to.  However, when opening this HTML file that has the image displayed on it, it comes up as a broken image.  I'm wondering why this is.

Thanks.

Comment: Img tag need to close first and second thing attribute alt is required.the image not work when user have proxy.

Comment: Those things are required for XHTML. Also, the second answer is already correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You 'll need to establish a secure connection to do that. When the browser comes across the url you have placed as src of the image it sends out a request to that server, which responds by offering different encryption methods it supports. But since you 'll be browsing the page as http data you won't be able to understand the response (which is supposed to be image data if the other side is http and now happens to be a query for encryption method). In short you are missing an SSL layer to make your communication sensible and therefore you see a broken image.

Comment: Yep, I got it working the end of yesterday and you are correct, sir. + rep for you because I appreciate the response.

Answer (score -1):

Try making it a background image in your css.

*edit* I am getting down voted for this question. I should have prefaced that I am not sure and was taking a wild guess, if anything to offer an idea that was not presented by the asker to help solve the problem :)

Comment: This particular page has no corresponding CSS, would you recommend I make one?  Or would there be an easier way to do this without creating a CSS?

Comment: I don't know if it will help with your VS problem, but for the most part, if you are able to use CSS, you should. There may be exceptions to this, but I can't think of any.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but this is really only a test page that will never be used for anything, I see no reason to bother creating a CSS.

Comment: I don't see how this solves the issue the OP is having. Namely: Visual Studio isn't loading files over HTTPS.

Comment: I didn't adequately explain it at first, and it also doesn't show up in a browser when opening the HTML file, but yeah either way I don't see what this would do.